# Showing MahApps.Metro dialogue from view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

I want to implement LINQToTwitter in my WPF desktop application. Therefore I have to secure it by using OAuth. On the documentation page from L2T I have an example for a console application, but not for a WPF application.

I thought I'd use a simple dialogue which prompts the user to enter a PIN. This is possible with MahApps.metro of course.

Now my question is: How would I do this in Caliburn.Micro. Of course my view model is not inheriting from MetroWindow, but from Screen.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get the **IWindowManager** in your main ViewModel, then use the **ShowDialog()** method by passing in your dialog's view model.